# Camera App not working (app Crashes) error: unfortunately the app has stopped in HTC Desire 516

Tags: android

I have implemented camera in android . its working in all mobile excluding `HTC Desire 516`.

please anyone help me that what is reason behind this. why not working in `HTC Desire 516` mobile.

when I clicking on button to show camera, it is crashing.

is there any difference hardware or software from other mobile which in not suitable for this mobile?

Comment: Off course. Different phone has different Hardware and  software support.

Comment: can you please post the logcat?

Comment: i have written same code and its working all mobile excluding HTC Desire 516 only. can you tell the exact reason behind this?

Comment: It's very difficult to solve device specific issue.

Comment: upload your code you did, and the logcat error ;)